# FFMPEG help me with image sequence - how to right render?

Tags: ffmpeg

In general, a problem whose solution I have not found anywhere. The original video (14 minutes 48 seconds) was turned into frames by the team:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -framerate 59.94 -start_number "%6d.png"
```

It turned out *53829* frames.
After a month of frame changes, I decide to put the video back together. There are the same number of frames - *53829*.
The first command I tried out:

```
ffmpeg -i "FRAMES/%6.png" -frame rate 59.94 -crf 15 "video_new.mp4"
```

After 10 minutes, I noticed that the fps in the output shows 25 and I pause the render.
I'm already trying this:

```
ffmpeg -i "FRAMES/%6d.png" -r 59.94 -crf 15 -y "video_new.mp4"
```

An hour later, I see that the frames have become *61000+* (?), the time is somewhere around 45. Stopped rendering.
Then on various forums they said that you need to use vsync
tried 0, 1, 2 - all to no avail. The video turns out to be 35 minutes+.
**WHAT TO DO HELP**

Comment: Attention, I can no longer get the frames from the original video, because they have been changed

Comment: Shouldn't it be -framerate 59.94 instead of -frame rate 59.94...maybe the fps of 25 is just what your processor can render per second...why not let the process go until de end?

Comment: @RicardoBohner This sounds exactly like whats going on

Comment: Place the `-r 59.64` before the `-i`

Comment: when I did -r 59.94 - wrote that fps was 59.94
however, when the video was ready, it was 35 minutes
MediaInfo says that there was a variable frame rate - 25 min, 59.94 max 
I don't think it depends on the processor, because it's an i7

Comment: Before `-i` defines the fps of the input

Comment: I'll try it later
because now I've imported the frames into sony vegas and he himself realized that the video is 14 minutes 58 seconds. Well, of course, I pre-configured the project for 59.94 fps

Comment: `-r` after input name is the fps of the output, but the fps of the input is 25fps (default). Frames are duplicated to form 59.94fps from 25fps input.

Comment: It sounds interesting, I will definitely try and write the result!

Comment: In the meantime, add your answer so that I can immediately choose it as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the answer is:
[Rotem](https://superuser.com/users/635712/rotem) was almost right in pointing out that fps input should be specified before i:

> Before -i defines the fps of the input –
> [Rotem](https://superuser.com/users/635712/rotem)

But, not -r:

> Before -i defines the fps of the input – [Rotem](https://superuser.com/users/635712/rotem)

Need -frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 59.94 -i "FRAMES/%6d.png" -crf 15 "new_video.mp4"
```

Then it changes the fps input and the video is rendered correctly. However, for some reason the video did not turn out as smooth as the original one, I had to choose the option that turned out in Sony Vegas. But that's another question...